# Java JFrame displaying initialisation content when losing focus

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jmenubar

My application uses the BorderLayout to display content in the frame. I also have a menubar at the top so other frames can be toggled to show. When I launch the application, each of these content areas of the frame are given a JPanel with the centre loaded with a 'startup screen' and once some background initialisation has been completed, the panel is then change to start displaying information post-initialisation. This panel is then updated 5 times every second, controlled by a loop.

When I select the menubar the display of the centre panel reverts back to that of startup screen. When I deselect the menubar the panel reverts to that of the correct one to be displayed. Debugging this leads to the entire Eclipse environment crashing.

Does anyone know what may be causing this? I'm not sure what code to show here so if you require more information I will edit this as such.

Answer (score 2):

1.have look at [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), be sure that GUI is created especially visible wrapped into `invokeLater()`

2.last code lines in the Swing GUI constructor would be

code

```
   myFrame.pack();
   myFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

3.for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)